# Trying to optimize VBA code to create worksheets

Tags: vba, excel

I am learning to clean my code and make it more efficient, however I'm having trouble with my code, because most of the post about the subject are specified to a given code. The code below looks like a lot, but it's the same step for different sheets (the code below is for two sheets, there are five more sheets).

```
Sub Formule_Code()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

'Compliance
Worksheets("WIP extract").Activate
    Range("A1").Select
        LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row

Range("A" & LastRow).Select
    Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.End(xlDown).End(xlToRight)).Copy

Worksheets("Compliance").Activate
    LastRowC = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
        Range("A" & LastRowC).Select
            ActiveCell.PasteSpecial xlPasteAll

    'Kolom G
LastRowSumG_C = Cells(Rows.Count, 7).End(xlUp).Offset(-1, 0).Row
LastRowFormG_C = Cells(Rows.Count, 7).End(xlUp).Row

Range("G" & LastRowFormG_C).Formula = "=SUM(G42:G" & LastRowSumG_C & ")"
Range("E8").Formula = "=SUM(G42:G" & LastRowSumG_C & ")"

    'Kolom I
LastRowSumI_C = Cells(Rows.Count, 9).End(xlUp).Offset(-1, 0).Row
LastRowFormI_C = Cells(Rows.Count, 9).End(xlUp).Row

Range("I" & LastRowFormI_C).Formula = "=SUM(I42:I" & LastRowSumI_C & ")"
Range("F8").Formula = "=SUM(I42:I" & LastRowSumI_C & ")"

    'Kolom K
LastRowSumK_C = Cells(Rows.Count, 11).End(xlUp).End(xlUp).Offset(-1, 0).Row
LastRowFormK_C = Cells(Rows.Count, 11).End(xlUp).End(xlUp).Row

Range("K" & LastRowFormK_C).Formula = "=SUM(K42:K" & LastRowSumK_C & ")"
Range("G8").Formula = "=SUM(K42:K" & LastRowSumK_C & ")"

    'Kolom L
LastRowSumL_C = Cells(Rows.Count, 12).End(xlUp).End(xlUp).End(xlUp).Offset(-1, 0).Row
LastRowFormL_C = Cells(Rows.Count, 12).End(xlUp).End(xlUp).End(xlUp).Row

Range("L" & LastRowFormL_C).Formula = "=SUM(L42:L" & LastRowSumL_C & ")"
Range("H8").Formula = "=SUM(L42:L" & LastRowSumL_C & ")"

Range(Cells(Rows.Count, "L").End(xlUp).Offset(1), Cells(Rows.Count, "L")).EntireRow.Clear

Range("F11").Formula = "=SUM(H8 +- F12)"
Range("G11").Formula = "=SUM(H8 +- G12)"

LastRowStaff = Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Offset().Row
LastRowExpense = Cells(Rows.Count, 12).End(xlUp).Offset(-5, 0).Row

Range("F12").Formula = "=SUMIF(D42:D" & LastRowStaff & ",""*Accrual*"", L42:L" & LastRowExpense & ")"
Range("G12").Formula = "=SUMIF(D42:D" & LastRowStaff & ",""*Accrual*"", L42:L" & LastRowExpense & ")"

Range("P42") = "Check"
Range("Q42") = "ID"

Range("P43").FormulaArray = "=IFERROR(INDEX(Lijst!$A$2:$A$247,MATCH(1,--(SEARCH(TRANSPOSE(Lijst!$A$2:$A$247),O43)>0),0),0),""Z"")"
    Range("P43").Select
        Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("P43:P1000")

Range("Q43").Formula = "=IF(P43<>P44,1,0)"
    Range("Q43").Select
        Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("Q43:Q1000")

    Rows("42:42").Select
    Selection.AutoFilter
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Compliance").AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Compliance").AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key:= _
        Range("P42"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:= _
        xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Compliance").AutoFilter.Sort
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With

    Columns("P:Q").Select
    Range("P25").Activate
    Selection.EntireColumn.Hidden = True

Dim rngc As Range, rc As Long

Set rngc = Range("Q8:Q3276")

For rc = rngc.Count To 1 Step -1
    If rngc(rc).Value = 1 Then
        rngc(rc + 1).EntireRow.Insert
        rngc(rc + 1).EntireRow.Select

    With Selection.Interior
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent1
        .TintAndShade = 0.599993896298105
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With
    Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalDown).LineStyle = xlNone
    Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalUp).LineStyle = xlNone
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeLeft)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeTop)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeRight)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    Selection.Borders(xlInsideVertical).LineStyle = xlNone
    Selection.Borders(xlInsideHorizontal).LineStyle = xlNone
    Range("A35").Select

    End If
Next rc

    Columns("R:R").Select
    Range("R31").Activate
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Selection.Clear
    Range("O31").Select

Application.Goto Reference:=Range("a1"), Scroll:=True


'-----------------------------
'Advies
Worksheets("WIP extract").Activate
    Range("A" & LastRow).Select
        Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.End(xlDown).End(xlToRight)).Copy

Worksheets("Advies").Activate
    LastRowA = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
        Range("A" & LastRowA).Select
            ActiveCell.PasteSpecial xlPasteAll

    'Kolom G
LastRowSumG_A = Cells(Rows.Count, 7).End(xlUp).Offset(-1, 0).Row
LastRowFormG_A = Cells(Rows.Count, 7).End(xlUp).Row

Range("G" & LastRowFormG_A).Formula = "=SUM(G42:G" & LastRowSumG_A & ")"
Range("E8").Formula = "=SUM(G42:G" & LastRowSumG_A & ")"

    'Kolom I
LastRowSumI_A = Cells(Rows.Count, 9).End(xlUp).Offset(-1, 0).Row
LastRowFormI_A = Cells(Rows.Count, 9).End(xlUp).Row

Range("I" & LastRowFormI_A).Formula = "=SUM(I42:I" & LastRowSumI_A & ")"
Range("F8").Formula = "=SUM(I42:I" & LastRowSumI_A & ")"

    'Kolom K
LastRowSumK_A = Cells(Rows.Count, 11).End(xlUp).End(xlUp).Offset(-1, 0).Row
LastRowFormK_A = Cells(Rows.Count, 11).End(xlUp).End(xlUp).Row

Range("K" & LastRowFormK_A).Formula = "=SUM(K42:K" & LastRowSumK_A & ")"
Range("G8").Formula = "=SUM(K42:K" & LastRowSumK_A & ")"

    'Kolom L
LastRowSumL_A = Cells(Rows.Count, 12).End(xlUp).End(xlUp).End(xlUp).Offset(-1, 0).Row
LastRowFormL_A = Cells(Rows.Count, 12).End(xlUp).End(xlUp).End(xlUp).Row

Range("L" & LastRowFormL_A).Formula = "=SUM(L42:L" & LastRowSumL_A & ")"
Range("H8").Formula = "=SUM(L42:L" & LastRowSumL_A & ")"

Range(Cells(Rows.Count, "L").End(xlUp).Offset(1), Cells(Rows.Count, "L")).EntireRow.Clear

Range("F11").Formula = "=SUM(H8 +- F12)"
Range("G11").Formula = "=SUM(H8 +- G12)"

LastRowStaff = Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Offset().Row
LastRowExpense = Cells(Rows.Count, 12).End(xlUp).Offset(-5, 0).Row

Range("F12").Formula = "=SUMIF(D42:D" & LastRowStaff & ",""*Accrual*"", L42:L" & LastRowExpense & ")"
Range("G12").Formula = "=SUMIF(D42:D" & LastRowStaff & ",""*Accrual*"", L42:L" & LastRowExpense & ")"

Range("P42") = "Check"
Range("Q42") = "ID"

Range("P43").FormulaArray = "=IFERROR(INDEX(Lijst!$A$2:$A$247,MATCH(1,--(SEARCH(TRANSPOSE(Lijst!$A$2:$A$247),O43)>0),0),0),""Z"")"
    Range("P43").Select
        Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("P43:P1000")

Range("Q43").Formula = "=IF(P43<>P44,1,0)"
    Range("Q43").Select
        Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("Q43:Q1000")

    Rows("42:42").Select
    Selection.AutoFilter
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Advies").AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Advies").AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key:= _
        Range("P42"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:= _
        xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Advies").AutoFilter.Sort
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With

    Columns("P:Q").Select
    Range("P25").Activate
    Selection.EntireColumn.Hidden = True

Dim rnga As Range, ra As Long

Set rnga = Range("Q8:Q3276")

For ra = rnga.Count To 1 Step -1
    If rnga(ra).Value = 1 Then
        rnga(ra + 1).EntireRow.Insert
        rnga(ra + 1).EntireRow.Select

    With Selection.Interior
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent1
        .TintAndShade = 0.599993896298105
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With
    Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalDown).LineStyle = xlNone
    Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalUp).LineStyle = xlNone
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeLeft)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeTop)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeRight)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    Selection.Borders(xlInsideVertical).LineStyle = xlNone
    Selection.Borders(xlInsideHorizontal).LineStyle = xlNone
    Range("A35").Select

    End If
Next ra

    Columns("R:R").Select
    Range("R31").Activate
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Selection.Clear
    Range("O31").Select

Application.Goto Reference:=Range("a1"), Scroll:=True
```

Any suggestions / help is appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Can you tell us more about what the code is doing and why?

Comment: Time allowing, try to [get best value out of CodeReview@SE](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2436/how-to-get-the-best-value-out-of-code-review-asking-questions?r=SearchResults&s=1|36.2985).

Comment: See [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba)... that's a good start. Also any time you have `Range` or `Cells` or `Rows` or `Columns`, etc., make sure they are qualified with the `Workbook` and `Worksheet` they are in/on.

Comment: Also, Activate, Select and "Active-anything" are things to avoid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This review is going to be short, because it will cover ground that has been covered many times in Code Review. Searching previous articles should provide more information.

1. Use `Option Explicit` at the top of modules every time. Always.
   ***Always*** (search: Option Explicit).
2. Properly indent your code for readability and maintainability.
   (search: indent code)
3. Avoid using select and activate unless you particularly want to draw
   something to the user's attention.
   (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba
   is a good start as @BigBen noted).
4. Always fully qualify any reference to Range or Cells. Using a
   qualified `With` block does count. (search: qualify ranges)

Once the basics have been addressed, the code itself (as intended, not as currently presented) can then be reviewed. At the moment it is a bit too hard to read.

Why do you have `.End` three times?

```
Cells(Rows.Count, 12).End(xlUp).End(xlUp).End(xlUp).Row
```

An additional hint is to declare and assign a `Workbook` and `Worksheet` object for the book/sheet(s) that you want to manipulate. When using the variable, the VBA IDE Intellisense will function and aid you in useful properties and methods. When not assigned to a variable, these commands (e.g. `ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("WIP extract")`) will return a generic Object and the Intellisense does not function.